# unable to start couchdb as non-root

Tags: couchdb, rhel7

With couchdb 1.6 in RedHat 7 installation, I am unable to run it as any non-root user. For a regular user it shows

```
    (no error lo{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{erl_prim_loader,check_file_result,3,[]},
{init,patch_dir,2,[]},{init,'-patch_path/2-lc$^0/1-0-',2,[]},{init,eval_script,8,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}gger present) error: "Error in process <0.2.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{erl_prim_loader,check_file_result,3,[]},{init,patch_dir,2,[]},{init,'-patch_path/2-lc$^0/1-0-',2,[]},{init,eval_script,8,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}\n"
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

while running it as couchdb user I get

```
(no error logger present) e{"init terminating in do_boot",{badarg,[{erl_prim_loader,check_file_result,3,[]},{init,patch_dir,2,[]},{init,'-patch_path/2-lc$^0/1-0-',2,[]},{init,eval_script,8,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
rror: "Error in process <0.2.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{erl_prim_loader,check_file_result,3,[]},{init,patch_dir,2,[]},{init,'-patch_path/2-lc$^0/1-0-',2,[]},
{init,eval_script,8,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}\n"
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

any suggestions how can i run it as non-root user, I have scripts that need to automatically run and stop couchdb. it runs as a regular user.

couchdb runs fine with root user.

Comment: What port you have bind? For ports in lower then 1025 you need to be root.

Comment: it binds at 5489 i.e at default port

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how to do this on Red Hat, but the various installing instructions is documented in the system specific install guides:

https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installation#System_specific_installation_guides

Here is what I do for ubuntu - create a user and give it ownership to the couchdb folders:

```
sudo adduser --disabled-login --disabled-password --no-create-home couchdb

sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/log/couchdb
sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb
sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/run/couchdb

sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/logrotate.d/couchdb /etc/logrotate.d/couchdb
sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/init.d/couchdb  /etc/init.d

sudo update-rc.d couchdb defaults
```